# How to move multiple input boxes

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to align the two cells for the address input. The one that is inline I can shift, but the ones that are not I do know know how to shift right. If I could get some creative feed back I would appreciate it.

```css
.EMBody {
  position: relative;
  background-color: navajowhite;
}

.EMSpace {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.EMAdj {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section class="EMBody">
  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street address">
    <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="Zip">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="9999999999">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email@email.com">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Brief Message: </label>
    <textarea cols="25" rows="5" class="message" placeholder="Please give a brief discription of your Iguana issues. Green or Spiny Tailed? In the attics, flowerbed, canal?"></textarea>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use CSS-Grid in your case. However this requires you to change your HTML Markup a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nth-child :

```css
.EMBody {
  position: relative;
  background-color: navajowhite;
}

.EMSpace {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.EMAdj {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 60%;
}
input:nth-child(3),input:nth-child(4)
{
  margin-left:104px;
}
```

```html
<section class="EMBody">
  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Full Name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Street address">
    <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="Zip">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="9999999999">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email@email.com">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="EMSpace">Brief Message: </label>
    <textarea cols="25" rows="5" class="message" placeholder="Please give a brief discription of your Iguana issues. Green or Spiny Tailed? In the attics, flowerbed, canal?"></textarea>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you are off by 2px because of the border thickness. Also will cause a few mis-alignments if the font size is changed because of user settings (readability).

Comment: Thank you for that line of code it made a world of difference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fully responsive solution would be to use CSS-Grid. THis would allow you to cut the code down a lot.

simply use a 2 column layout and let the label for the address span 3 rows.

```css
.EMBody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.EMBody {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.EMBody label:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="EMBody">

  <label class="EMSpace">Full Name:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">

  <label class="EMSpace">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Street address">
  <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="City">
  <input type="text" class="EMAdj" placeholder="Zip">

  <label class="EMSpace">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="9999999999">

  <label class="EMSpace">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email@email.com">

  <label class="EMSpace">Brief Message: </label>
  <textarea cols="25" rows="5" class="message" placeholder="Please give a brief discription of your Iguana issues. Green or Spiny Tailed? In the attics, flowerbed, canal?"></textarea>
  
</section>
```

Comment: I attempted to use your version, but it broke the rest of my code. I will have to learn more to be able to trouble shout that issue. Another posted the use of input:nth-child(3),input:nth-child(4)
{
  margin-left:104px;
} which worked